# How can I make sure that Local TeX Live is not older than remote repository?

Tags: mactex, rmarkdown

I have downloaded MacTeX-2020 to be able to knit R Markdown documents to PDF in R Studio. I downloaded it yesterday and it is the 2020 version. When I try to knit to PDF in R Markdown, I get the error:

```
tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
! LaTeX Error: File `multirow.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile lab_test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See lab_test.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("tlmgr", args, ...) :
  running command ''tlmgr' search --file --global '/multirow.sty'' had status 1
Execution halted
```

I am not sure how this has happened because I downloaded the 2020 MacTeX version so surely Local TeX Live should also be the 2020 version and not 2019 version? How can I upgrade the Local TeX Live to the 2020 version? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: After downloading MacTeX-2020 did you install the package by double clicking the .pkg file? Also, how is your R Markdown configured and why is it trying to run tomography?

Comment: Jessie, welcome to tex.stackexchange. Based on my searching, it looks like R uses something called tinytex, and you may have to reinstall it to point it at this year's TeX Live (see [tinytex FAQ item 11](https://yihui.org/tinytex/faq/)). Apparently this is a second TeX installation that ignores your MacTeX, and installs its own stuff as-needed.

Comment: I encountered this issue as well. Had attempted to resolve by reinstalling MacTex and Xquartz, neither worked. Followed link and instructions suggested by Adam Maxwell, this provided the resolution. Thanks Adam!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! Adam, I followed your link and it provided the resolution (I also had to follow FAQ item 13 too). Cheers!